# Is it possible to draw over the status bar in react native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a "drawer menu" component. The menu is an overlay that comes form the side and partially covers the main screen.

Is it possible to make it partially cover the status bar too? I have seen this effect in Google Inbox.

[image: Drawer menu covering the status bar]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make it partially cover the status bar. You can create a view component and you can position it with an absolute position. Based on this [library](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/blob/master/index.js), you can add this style to a view component

```
{
  right: 0,
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  position: 'absolute',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```

Then you can add a custom width to the same view so the drawer doesn't take all the screen width.

You can also use the react-native [DrawerLayoutAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html), but this component is only available on android.